# How to make a RecyclerView adapter to get 3 items of an arraylist in every row

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

I need some help with a RecyclerView.Adapter. I pass to a recyclerview adapter an arraylist of object Dart, I have an simple_list_item.xml where it has 3 textviews (dart1Txt, dart2Txt and dart3Txt). I want the adapter to get the values from the arraylist and fill the textviews. For example I have the values 10, 20, 30, 3, 5, 6 and I want to be printed like that

10 20 30

3 5 6

and so on.

I cant understand how to make this. This my onBindViewHolder.

```
onBindViewHolder(RoundsStatsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position){
   Dart dart = mDarts.get(position);
   holder.dart1Textview.setText(String.valueOf(dart.getScore()));
}
```

**Update for more info:**
I have a Dart object which has a field dartScore. I sent an arrayList of Dart objects and I want the recyclerview adapter to get the first 3 Darts from the arraylist and fill the 3 textviews with the dartScore, after that take the next 3 Darts from the arraylist and to a new row fill again the 3 textviews and so on.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Community. You can follow this link http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: @Shashanth thanks for your answer. I have updated my question with more info to understand better my problem.

Comment: Maybe try Dart dart2 = mDarts.get(position + 1); and position + 2 for other 2 textviews? ViewHolder will handle the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either split your Darts List in a DartTuple List:

```
private class DartTuple {
    Dart dart1, dart2, dart3;
}
```

or if you are sur that your list contains always 3*x items, you can simply change your adapter like this

```
onBindViewHolder(RoundsStatsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position){
   position = position * 3; // to use multiple 3 increment
   Dart dart1 = mDarts.get(position);
   Dart dart2 = mDarts.get(position + 1);
   Dart dart3 = mDarts.get(position + 2);
   /* your layout
      holder.dart1Textview.setText(String.valueOf(dart.getScore()));
   */
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDarts.size()/3;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I am not very familiar with tuples can you give some more info. Thanks!